# Obtain all elements in a defined set in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a set S which is really made from taking cartesian products on smaller sets. For example, maybe A={0,1,2}, and S=A^3. Is there a function or efficient way to obtain all elements in S without having to define each of the 3^3 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `expand.grid` it takes multiple lists and does cartesian product on them

```
S <- list(0,1,2)
expand.grid(S,S,S)
```

here's the output:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     0    0    0
2     1    0    0
3     2    0    0
4     0    1    0
5     1    1    0
6     2    1    0
7     0    2    0
8     1    2    0
9     2    2    0
10    0    0    1
11    1    0    1
12    2    0    1
13    0    1    1
14    1    1    1
15    2    1    1
16    0    2    1
17    1    2    1
18    2    2    1
19    0    0    2
20    1    0    2
21    2    0    2
22    0    1    2
23    1    1    2
24    2    1    2
25    0    2    2
26    1    2    2
27    2    2    2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to use an argument to tell R how many times to repeat a set? I am thinking about something like ```function(S,n)``` to give the same output when n=3, but it doesn't seem that ```expand.grid``` can accommodate that?

Comment: @Pburg I think you could use a for loop where it keeps computing `expand.grid()` for `S` and a temporary variable